# How should I choose a reinforcement learning algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, reference-request

I'm starting a new RL project. I'm familiar with Deep Q-Learning because of an old project where I used it, but I'm not sure I chose correctly back then.

Why should or shouldn't I choose DQN, or any other RL algorithm/method for a problem? By which criteria should I judge an RL algorithm? Is there any set of guidelines to help you choose a specific RL algorithm for a problem?

I did some research, but wasn't satisfied.